# ASP.NET C# "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, types

OK, so I'm using Mono on Mac OS X to work simple "applications" using ASP.NET and C# and I'm having two issues with my code.

Here is my Default.aspx presentation markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="project1.Tree" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>project1_test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField id="hd_Height" runat="server" />
        <p><asp:label runat="server" id="lblOutput" /></p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrowBy" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="btnGrow" runat="server" Text="Grow!!!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CodeBehind C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace project1
{
    public partial class Tree : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        private void PersistHeight(int height)
        {
            this.Session["height"] = height;
        }

        private int RestoreHeight()
        {
            return (int)this.Session[0];
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get
            {
               return int.Parse(hd_Height.Value).ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                hd_Height.Value = value.ToString();
            }
        }
        public int height = 0;

        public void Grow(int heightToGrow) {
            height += heightToGrow;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(Object Source, EventArgs E)    
        {    
            string msg = "Let's plant a tree!<br/>";        

            msg += "I've created a tree with a height of " +    
            this.height + " metres.<br/>";    

            lblOutput.Text = msg;
        }

        public virtual void btnGrowClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            txtGrowBy.Text = this.heightToGrow;
        }

    }
}
```

Mono gives me the following two errors:

1)  `cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'` 
line `return int.Parse(hd_Height.Value).ToString();`
2)  `Type 'project1.Tree' does not contain a definition for 'heightToGrow' and no extension method 'heightToGrow' of type 'project1.Tree could be found`
 line `txtGrowBy.Text = this.heightToGrow;`

Comment: So what exactly is causing you confusion? The error messages are pretty clear. The reason I am asking this is because it seems like you are lacking certain programming fundamentals yet at the same time you are trying to write moderately complex code.

Comment: @ChaosPandion We all start somewhere ... remember where you came from, even if you have to go back to when you were a kid.  I've seen much worse questions than this one.

Comment: @Richard - Yeah I know... when I am tired my mental defenses that stop me from being an a-hole weaken.

Comment: Haha, thanks for everything guys, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1: Height is int, you can't return a string in it's get.
For 2: HeightToGrow is not a field or property of your class, so you can't use it like that.
I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve in 2, but you may want to call `Grow`, and then get the tree's height.

Comment: The issue here is that you are essentially repeating the detailed error message that the OP posted.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to do, is set the `txtGrowBy.Text` equal to the parameter of the `Grow()` method of `this` or `tree1`.  I was told that I didn't need to create a new object, because IIS already creates one.  How do I do this, then?

Comment: @ChaosPndion: I thought I was explaining the errors in human readable language, so that the OP can understand what he was doing wrong. I actually still think so.

Comment: @BOSS: the parameter of Grow(..) is heightToGrow. You'll have to get it from somewhere (e.g. a textbox). the sentence that contains "IIS" makes no sense, unless you replace "IIS" with ASP.NET - but even so, you'll still need to get the parameter for the method from somewhere.

Comment: @Oren - Maybe but it seems that @BOSS is missing so many fundamental concepts such as the idea of a type and a member of a type. Knowing what these things means is very important. It is kind of like picking up some paint and an easel and simply painting. Sure you might learn a thing or two but all the other painters that took the time to understand their craft will be light years ahead of you in no time.

Comment: @Chaos: They're very important. I didn't use those two terms. I think he got my remarks.

Comment: @Oren - Meh, don't listen to me. I probably take my craft way too seriously.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int Height 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    return int.Parse(hd_Height.Value).ToString(); 
  }
```

The property getter should return an int.  ToString returns a string.  The compiler will not implicitly convert that string to an int.  Remove the call to ToString.

---

```
public void Grow(int heightToGrow)
{ 
  height += heightToGrow; 
} 

public virtual void btnGrowClicked (object sender, EventArgs args) 
{ 
  txtGrowBy.Text = this.heightToGrow; 
}
```

`heightToGrow` is declared as a parameter for another method.  `this` does not have a `heightToGrow`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, the line

```
return int.Parse(hd_Height.Value).ToString()
```

is trying to return a string, for an integer type property.

Answer (score 1):

For 2: It's just saying that you have no field or property named "`heightToGrow`". It is defined in the `Grow` method, but that's not accessible outside that method.

Answer (score 1):

1) the property is of type int, and the ToString method tha you execute returns a string.

Or you change the property to a string property:

```
public string Height 
    { 
        get 
        { 
           return int.Parse(hd_Height.Value).ToString(); 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            hd_Height.Value = value;
        } 
    }
```

or you don't execute that ToString

```
public int Height 
    { 
        get 
        { 
           return int.Parse(hd_Height.Value); 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            hd_Height.Value = value.ToString(); 
        } 
    }
```

2) While doing this { ´this.heightToGrow; ´ you mean that you have a field with the name heightToGrow on the class... and I don't see it declared.

Declare that field:

```
private string heghtToGrow;
```